# What's the correct syntax for setting up memcached caching driver in EE 2.8+ with socket?

Tags: config, caching, config-overrides

In EE 2.8 and above, you can select 'Memcached' as your 'Caching Driver' under "Admin" => "General Configuration".

I am using one of Nexcess' "ExpressionEngine optimized" hosting plans, which lists "Memcached Back-End" as one of their features. I wanted to enable this, so I contacted their support folks. They set up a socket to use memcache.

However, when I select 'Memcached' as my caching driver, EE displays the error message "Cannot connect to Memcached, using File driver instead".

What is the correct syntax for my config file to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm glad you asked!

```
$config['cache_driver'] = 'memcached';
$config['memcached'] = array(
  array(
    'host' => '/var/tmp/memcached.sock',
    'port' => 0,
    'weight' => 1,
  )
);
```

Adding that to your config.php should do the trick, assuming you list the correct socket location and port.

(this is me answering my own question, because I searched and searched and couldn't find this info anywhere.)